# Watir Element exists but not present, but is visible in screenshot

Tags: watir-webdriver

For some reason Watir is saying the footer of my page is not visible.

I have my tests setup to take screenshots, and I can see the footer on the screenshot of the page.

I take the screenshot by doing:

```
@browser.driver.save_screenshot(output + "/" + screenshot)
```

Testing lines in the code:

```
puts "waiting for bottom sticker"
Watir::Wait.until { @browser.div(:id => "bottom-sticker").exists? }
puts "bottom sticker found"
puts "bottom sticker exists: " + @browser.div(:id => "bottom-sticker").exists?.to_s
puts "bottom sticker present: " + @browser.div(:id => "bottom-sticker").present?.to_s
puts "bottom sticker visible: " + @browser.div(:id => "bottom-sticker").visible?.to_s
```

Test log:

> ```
>   waiting for bottom sticker
>   bottom sticker found
>   bottom sticker exists: true
>   bottom sticker present: false
>   bottom sticker visible: false
> ```

Watir is reporting other elements in the page as visible and present. The bottom-sticker div is a child of body so its not being hidden by a parent.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you take the screenshot before or after you tested if the bottom sticker was "present"? If the screenshot was after, it could be a timing issue. Try waiting for the bottom sticker to be present rather than just existing. If that does not work, it would help to share the HTML and CSS that show the problem.

Comment: if I do a wait_until_present on the div it times out

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare can you give url of this web-page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this issue was not due to watir, but instead originated from selenium.  I eventually found this link to [Selenium docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#determining-visibility).  I did have overflow:hidden styling on my div and removing it made the contents available in Watir.

There must be some issue in Selenium as the content definitely wasn't overflowing, and was definitely visible in the screenshots taken using the selenium browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the element is present.

Right now you are waiting for it to exists, which means it is only waiting until the element is found in the html and not on the screen. Waiting until present will wait until the element is found in the HTML **AND** is on the screen. Reference the notes below to understand which assertion to use:

There are three different methods used in Watir for determining an object's state in the browser. They are .exists?, .present?, and .visible?.

The preferred method is .present?

The differences between the three are:

.exists?

- returns true if the element is in the HTML (whether displayed on the
  screen or not)
- returns false if the element is not in the HTML

.present?

- returns true if the element is in the HTML and displayed on the
  screen
- returns false if the element is in the HTML and not displayed on the
  screen OR if the element is not in the HTML

.visible?

- returns true if the element is in the HTML and displayed on the
  screen
- returns false if the element is in the HTML and not displayed on the
  screen
- throws an ERROR if the element is not in the HTML

Comment: using wait_until_present times out.  Printing the html contents of the element prior to doing the wait until exists shows the expected contents are there.

Comment: Ah ok. Well I'm happy you were able to figure it out! :)